# Java concurrency - marbles moving around a circle

Tags: java, concurrency

Let's imagine a simple Java program, where there are 5 2D marbles moving around in a circle in a fixed order. You can control the speed of every marble keeping in mind that slower marble is blocking the marble moving faster (they can't overtake). They all move in one direction in a circle. What would be the best way to program this? The idea is to assign a separate thread to every marble, that's actually one of the requirements.
Then I create five threads, synchronize the "move" method on some object common to all threads. The next step is checking whether I can move the marble forward, if there is some free space. So before I move, I check if there is free space and then take action. Is it necessary or at least a good idea to use wait() and notify() mechanism here?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps you could try this yourself and then come back here with some actual code when you have specific bugs you can't figure out.

Comment: What would you wait on and notify for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not going to code your homework for you, but here is a high level look at it.

You will need each marble to update it's position at regular intervals, so some type of looping is required. This loop is commonly known as a game loop. Here is a discussion of various types of them, going from simple to complex. http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0 For your project, something simply may be sufficient, but I don't know the requirements of it.

Each time a marble tries to move, it must check to make sure it isn't being blocked. If you have the move method synchronized, as you mentioned, then only one marble should be able to move at a time, so that should avoid concurrency issues.

Except for using a `Thread.sleep` in your game loops, I don't see any reason for you to doing any waiting. Java has a `synchronize` keyword, which can be used to lock the shared object that you mentioned using for movement, to avoid the concurrency issues. So I don't believe `wait` and `notify` are necessary.

Just my thoughts, I hope it is of some help.

Comment: Yeah, for making your loop take a more consistent amount of time (though Thread.sleep isn't totally consistent). Check out the link I included.

Comment: So even though the method I'd use is synchronized on a shared object, I still have to check if the marble is able to move (check if its next position would cause an overlap with the next marble)?

Comment: Yeah. You'll want to put the check for that inside the move method (or another method that is called by the move method), so that it is called each time a marble tries to move. Imagine if all the marbles are already touching each other, and the one in the back tries to move forward. None of the other marbles are moving at that moment, so the marble is able to call the move method, but it shouldn't actually be allowed to move because then it would be overlapping the marble directly ahead of it.

Comment: Is it necessary to synchronize the move method?

Comment: If it isn't synchronized in some way, then you could have two marbles trying to move at the same time, and they could potentially end up overlapping. So yes.